# No consume mi web Service desde Ajax Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webservice

Este es mi codigo

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/QM/QMUI/WebServicePrueba.asmx/ObtenerCategorias',
    //url: "CategoriaK.aspx/ObtenerCategorias",//ojitos
    data: "{IdCategoria :" + -1 + " }",   // -1 trae la lista completa
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (datos) {

        //Valido si hubo Error, si es diferente a -1 es que hubo error
        var existeError = datos.d.indexOf('Error');
        if (existeError == -1) {
            registrosListado = JSON.parse(datos.d);
        }
        else {
            Error = datos.d;
            if (Error != "") {
                alert(Error);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Este es mi servicio web

```
#region <<ObtenerListadoCategorias>>
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string ObtenerCategorias(Int16 IdCategoria)
    {
        string mensaje = "";
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
        dbo.BaseDatos db = null;
        db = new dbo.BaseDatos(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn"].ToString());
        SqlParameter prmIdCategoria;

        try
        {
            prmIdCategoria = new SqlParameter("@IdCategoria", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            prmIdCategoria.Value = IdCategoria;


            DataTable = db.ObtenerDatosComoDataTable("spg_ListadoCategoria", prmIdCategoria);
            //dataset.TableName = "Usuario";
            mensaje = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mensaje = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Finalizar();
        }
        return mensaje;
    }
    #endregion
```

Este es mi servicio Web

[image: Es Mi servicio pasandole parametro -1]

[image: Si vuelvo a recargar ese link, me dice que ya no existe]

Sugerencias ??

Answer (score 2):

En tu código de jQuery estás declarando que vas a consumir un servicio de tipo `type: "POST",` sin embargo, como lo puedes consumir desde un navegador la lógica me dice que tu servicio **ASMX** es por default de tipo `GET`, cambia la siguiente línea en tu `ajax` y realiza la prueba:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost/QM/QMUI/WebServicePrueba.asmx/ObtenerCategorias',
    ....
```

O en su caso, declara en tu servicio `ASMX` de tipo `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta el WSDL en la url:

```
url: 'http://localhost/QM/QMUI/WebServicePrueba.asmx/ObtenerCategorias?WSDL',
```